# Suma con condicional en consulta de mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en un sistemita de proyectos pero para sacar un reporte ando haciendo una consulta en sql (la anexo abajo) esa esta bien pero quiero ver como agrego otro condicional, por ejemplo, que me sume los 'importe' de  'orden' y que sea 'tipo' de gasto 'admi'.  ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer o quien me orienta en esa consulta?

```
SELECT SUM(if(orden='1009',importe,0)) SumaCuenta FROM cuentas;

id      tipo    orden    importe
1       admin   1009     20
2       opera   1000     15
3       opera   1000     100
4       admin   1008     70
5       admin   1008     30
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En el where? cual es el problema?

Comment: Muchas gracias el detalle es que quiero sumar del campo 'orden' todos los de1008 su valor del campo 'importe' pero solo los que tengan el mismo dato del campo 'tipo' = admin y hay es donde ya no pude

Comment: Pero todas esas condiciones van el el where. No sabes haces un where?

Comment: no muy bien la verdad

Comment: Y leiste la documentacion sobre sql? sobre la clausula where?

Comment: apenas la ando checando para entenderle mejor y poderlo implementar bien

Comment: Perfecto.. intentalo, y si necesitas mas ayuda actualiza la pregunta y vemos de contestarte sobre los problemas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya quedo XD

SELECT SUM(if(orden='1009',importe,0)) SumaCuenta
FROM cuentas
WHERE tipo='admin';

Comment: Y porque, si solo buscas ese orden, entonces no esta tambien en el where? la respuesta, asi como esta, es de baja calidad porque no explica nada.